# Vim only show current line / hide every other line

Tags: search

**My question is if there is a possible way to hide everything except all text except the current line?**

---

Some background:
I have a really big JSON file which I just did a macro on and am doing a quick eyeball to see that everything looks alright.

What I'm currently doing is searching for a specific keyword and going next.

eg: `/"Name":` and holding `n` to go to the next result. (dw `n` is already mapped to `nZZ`)

This is really useful at the moment, but it's also very distracting to see other information on the top and bottom constantly changing.

Is there a possible way to hide everything except the current line (image for reference)?

[image: Image for reference]

Comment: Resize your window so it's height is that of a single row? ;)

Comment: @BLayer, even better, split and change its height to 1!

Comment: How about `:g/"Name":/print` ?

Comment: @Shahbaz Yep, you one-upped me. :)

Comment: @tivn thanks for your answer it's really good. anyway to print in color?

Comment: @Pyrons AFAIK, no. I also would love it if it is shown in color. BTW, the `print` can be eliminated actually. And then you can also put nothing between `//` to perform on preceeding search. So, basically, just `:g//` should work.

Comment: Or `:g/blah/#` if you want line numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can use 'Conceal' feature.
For example,

```
:match Conceal /^.*$/
:set conceallevel=3
```

All the lines except current one will be concealed.
If you do not like the 'Conceal' color,

```
:highlight Conceal NONE
```

When you finish, just do

```
:match
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is the best answer. Any easy way to do this in a function?

Comment: @Pyrons Just write `:function HideOtherLines()` on the line before it and `:endfunction` on the line after it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "vimgrep" to get all the results in a quickfix window and jump to the results you want to.

Not exactly what you're looking for but a workaround.

Example:

```
vimgrep /"Name":/j | cw
```

Note: Switch between quickfix window and the buffer using CTRL-W CTRL-W

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this would be to set all your highlighting groups to have the same foreground `ctermfg/guifg` and background `ctermbg/guibg` colours, and then use `set cursorline` and the `CursorLine` highlight group to change the colour of the current line.

However, an easier way to do it is to install the [Limelight plugin](https://github.com/junegunn/limelight.vim).

You'll need to add the following configuration to your `.vimrc` in order to make Limelight focus on a single line:

```
let g:limelight_bop = '^'
let g:limelight_eop = '$'
```

You can then switch Limelight on and off with the commands:

```
:Limelight 1
:Limelight!
```

*N.B. The `1` in the command above is an opacity/intensity parameter. If you do not include it, or use instead a value between `0` and `1`, then Limelight will dim down the other lines, but not hide them completely.*

Comment: Okay, that settles it. There is a plugin for _everything_!

Answer (score 0):

This solution looks simple enough :

```
:syntax match Ignore /^\(.*"Name":\)\@!.*$/ containedin=ALL
```